# Repository is changed after push on mercurial

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, hgignore

When I create repository and push on server and when we clone the repository in local system the files are come with red signal means they are **changed**.

When we compare both repository I found that the content of files in .hg folder is changed.
Can anyone pls tell me how to remove this problem!

**Edit:**
When we change the .hg folder the red icon becomes green!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take 1 modified (changed) file, watch the diff closely, and only see the difference is in new lines only, this is the classical newlines mess. 
(happens to most people when working crossplatform)

There is a ready to use Mercurial Extension, taking care of this is problem. 
It's called `eol`.
Learn how to use it and the problem from here:
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/EolExtension

Comment: This means the beyond compare (BC) tool is by default set up to ignore newline format changes. This is not necessarily a good thing.
BC has a setting to show white space/new line characters, and you shall see the only difference is the new lines. And this is Q.E.D. of my theory :)

Answer (score 0):

how do you push localy created repository to server? If there is no repo with same name(on server), you could not be able to create remote repo by push, you have to clone it to the server. Or, if there already is repository with same name, and you push some new localy created, there definitely will be something more in .hg on the server then on the local. Check if there isn't repo with same name on the server already. HTH

Comment: Whenever I change something in files first I commit then Push.

Comment: And repository is already created actually this problem arise yesterday!